# How to document a function in Octave?

Tags: matlab, documentation, octave

The `publish` function in [MATLAB](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/publish.html) works for both scripts and functions,
while the one for [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Publish-Octave-Script-Files.html#XREFpublish) works only for scripts: if I enter

```
publish myFunc.m
```

Octave gave

> error: publish: Only Octave script files can be published.

Am I able to publish a function in Octave? If yes, how?

Comment: Or should I turn to [other publishing tools](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/58438-which-tool-are-you-using-to-create-the-documentation-of-your-matlab-codes)?

Comment: This doesn't seem like a very good question. I'm randomly accepting one (to end this question) before I do more research on this topic. Thanks a lot for both answers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Octave Forge [`generate_html`](https://octave.sourceforge.io/generate_html/index.html) package which is meant to generate html of individual functions.  It is mostly used to generate the documentation of Octave Forge packages, and its defaults reflect that, but you could add any style you want.

This package will use the same help text that the `help` function in Octave sees which is the first block of comments in the file that does not start by `Copyright` or `Author`. You can have it in plain text but for nicer formatting, you can use [Texinfo](https://www.gnu.org/software/texinfo/manual/texinfo/texinfo.html).  In that case, the first line of the help text should be `-*- texinfo -*-`. There is a page on the Octave wiki with tips on how to write nice [help text](http://wiki.octave.org/Help_text) including a short section on Texinfo syntax (the actual Texinfo manual can be a bit overwhelming).

In addition to the help text, the `generate_html` package also identifies [`%!demo` blocks](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Demonstration-Functions.html) and generates a section with the demo code and output it generates, including figures.

The best way to see how help text and demo blocks work in Octave is to check the source (as @Andy pointed out in the comments).  For example, see the [source for `inpolygon`](http://hg.savannah.gnu.org/hgweb/octave/file/d133d90b495a/scripts/geometry/inpolygon.m) (scroll to the bottom to find the `%!demo` blocks, right before `%!test` and `%!error`).  The `generate_html` package generates [this page](https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/inpolygon.html) (note the Demonstration blocks).

Comment: Thank you! I tried to find some reference for appropriate comment syntax by searching `octave generate_html` but nothing interesting. Any pointers?

Comment: @FranklinYu it uses that function help text as the documentation and a function help text is the first block of comments in a file that does not start by Author or Copyright.

Comment: Oh, so that's the same with `publish`. I imagine the "see also" syntax to be the same as well. How do I write comment for arguments then? Like [here](https://octave.sourceforge.io/generate_html/function/html_help_text.html), a `<dl>` is generated somehow.

Comment: @FranklinYu UTSL! https://sourceforge.net/p/octave/generate_html/ci/default/tree/inst/html_help_text.m#l28 TL;DR: use "@table @samp"
and "@item"

Comment: @FranklinYu If you want to have more than just pain text, you will need to write the help [texinfo](https://www.gnu.org/software/texinfo/manual/texinfo/texinfo.html).  There is a shorter introduction in the Octave too on how to write [help text](http://wiki.octave.org/Help_text). But really, just look at the help text of the functions that already exist. Its just that the first line of the comments needs to be `-*- texinfo -*-`

Comment: @Andy Yes I totally forgot that those Octave packages are open-sourced, unlike MATLAB. Thanks!

Comment: @carandraug Oh that Octave Wiki page (composed by you?) helped so much; you should totally add that to your answer! However, I didn't find `-*- texinfo -*-` (I assume that's [Emacs magic comment](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Choosing-Modes.html)?) anywhere in that Wiki page. Should I add that? In addition, Does that works with [`help`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/help.html) from MATLAB as well? (That's AFAIK how MATLAB get help from libraries.) It would be best to keep MATLAB compatibility.

Comment: @FranklinYu go ahead and edit those wiki pages as you see fit. That's the reason they are a wiki in the first place. But I would second Andy comments.  The best way to see what works is to look into the existing source. I don't know Matlab but I believe it only supports plain text.

Comment: @carandraug I am thinking maybe there is a way to: feed Texinfo to Octave, while fallback to plain text in MATLAB. Is that possible? For example, document twice, once for Octave, and another for MATLAB?

Comment: In addition, how about appending anchor `#l90` to the end of the `inpolygon` source URL in the answer? (If only it supports range anchor, like GitHub's `#L90-L136`…)

Answer (score 2):

This is a "multiple questions in one" question, making lots of assumptions in between, so let's address those first:

**1.** I'll start by the question in the comment, since that's the easiest: Matlab's publisher is *not* a code documentation tool. It's a "make a quick report that includes both text and code to show at your supervisor meeting or write a quick point in a blog" tool. So the link you point to is simply irrelevant in this case, since that talks about documentation for matlab code.

**2.** The fact that matlab's publisher also "works for functions", particularly given the first point here, should be considered to be more of a bug than a feature, or at most as a trivial undocumented extension. If you look at the [matlab documentation](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/publish.html) for the publish command, you'll see it expects a filename, not a function with arguments, and the documentation only talks about scripts and makes no mention of 'function' compatibility.

**3.** Furthermore, even if you *did* want to use publisher as a "documentation tool", this is counterintuitive for functions in this format, since you need to provide arguments in order for publisher to work (which will not be shown in the actual report), you'll need a modified version that displays intermediate calculations (as opposed to your normal version which presumably does not), and the function just spews an ugly `ans= blabla` at the end of the report. If your end goal is documentation, it might be best to write a bespoke script for this anyway, showing proper usage and examples, like matlab does in its *actual* documentation.

---

Having said all that, ***yes, there is a 'cheat' you can do to include a function's code in your published report***, which is that, in octave (also matlab since R2016b), functions can be defined locally. A `.m` file that only contains function definitions is interpreted as a function file, but if there are other non-function-declaration instructions preceding the function definitions (other than comments), then it is seen as a script. So if you publish this script, you effectively get a published report with function code in it:

```
%% Adding function
% This function takes an input and adds 5 to it.

%% Example inputs
In = 10;

%% The function itself
% Marvel at its beauty!
function Out = myfun(In)

  %% Here is where the addition takes place.
  % It is a beautiful addition
  Out = In + 5;

end

%% Example use
Out = myfun(In)
```

(If you're not happy about having to create a 'wrapper script' manually, you can always create your own wrapper function that does this automatically).

However, both the matlab and octave publishers are limited tools *by design*. Like I said earlier, it's more of a "quick report to show numbers and plots to your supervisor" tool, rather than a "make nice documentation or professional reports" tool. Instead, I would invest in a nice automated latex workflow, and have a look at code formatting tools for displaying code, and simply wrap that code in a script that produces output to a file that you can then import into latex. It may sound like more work, but it's a lot more flexible and robust in the long term, particularly since the formatting commands can be very quirky as well as limited.

Comment: Ah. Sorry. Just realised, performing any "actual"  publisher formatting inside the function causes the function's definition to `end` first, before evaluating the remaining instructions in the file. So unless you intend to simply dump a function's code *as is* then you can't include formatting instructions inside a function. Your best bet is to write a script from scratch detailing the function's steps, with publisher formatting in mind.

Comment: So `publish` is not actually for documentation? Then does MATLAB provide any official documentation tools? I am actually looking for documentation tools; I just thought that "publishing" is the term for documentation in MATLAB. I feel like "cheating" is worse than no documentation; so I guess the question I linked should tell some true documentation tools?

Comment: Matlab documentation comes in two forms: what you see when you type `help` and what you get with `doc`. Matlab provides *some* tools such as `helprpt`, which gives you feedback as to whether your function includes all the "recommended" documentation features that would appear using the `help` command, i.e. short description, long description, examples, "see also" line, etc.  Furthermore, matlab has a very consistent "documentation" style for documentation accessed via the `doc` command, but those are produced separate to the function files (presumably using `publish` on corresponding scripts)

Comment: I would say that documenting your function with all the features required by the `help` command is both necessary and sufficient. It's up to you whether you want to publish more extensive documentation using `publish` (which has the added benefit of including images, for instance), and yes, the easiest way is to use `publish` on a script that demonstrates use of the function. But yes if you want something more automated, then `publish` isn't the way to go. I'm not familiar with the other tools you linked to though, so I can't advise you on that.

Comment: Did you mean that I should have `myfun.m` as the function, and `myfun_doc.m` as a script to `publish` from? That seems like a good option under MATLAB. By the way, `helprpt` seems undocumented? A simple search only gives me some answers on this site that simply mentioned it without much explanation. Is that a user script (like the one in [File Exchange](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/))?

Comment: Yes, to the first question. This is how matlab itself does it. Re `helprpt`, I think it may have been removed in recent versions of matlab, and moved to a graphical app instead. Have a look at the 'ribbons' / 'apps'. Sorry, I'm stuck with an older version so I can't help here.

Comment: Also, with regard to the other answer here by carandraug, `generate_html` is a nice option for functions, but it relies on the same features being present that `help` does; basically it converts the output of `help` into html (much like `helpwin` in matlab)

Comment: Help reports have indeed moved and are no longer available via the `helprpt` command. See here: https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/check-which-programs-have-help.html

Comment: I am wondering how will MATLAB's `help` treat those Texinfo markups? For `help` in Octave, those documentation fall back elegantly to plain text, removing all the tags like `@t{}`. I hope MATLAB do the same, but can't find any source discussing that. (For MATLAB, I would not ask for anything but `help`. That's what MathWorks provide; they are proprietary software!)

Comment: the texinfo syntax is exclusively an Octave thing, and as I understand it, it was there before a `publish` command was implemented, to create analogous docs for octave, but in latex. Matlab doesn't support it, and has always relied on a combination of `help`-supported features + separate documentation in html via a published script.

Comment: By saying "MATLAB doesn't support it" did you mean "MATLAB will convert it to plain text" or "MATLAB will generate anything (including garbage) from it"?

Comment: I mean matlab will complain of a syntax error, since it does not recognise the "#" character as a valid comment character, or any of the texinfo commands.

Comment: I use `%` which is also recognized by Octave, so I only worry about those texinfo tags.